Issue in Setting up the Local Environment for Testing the Azure Function using VS code
I am trying to Run and Debug the Python code using the VS code tool and I am getting the Module not found errors repeatedly and I am not able to progress on this further.
I tried using several sys path variables and tried importing the packages manually using pip but I am not able to install several packages as well.


please share you function code

Please provide the details of your issues in the text of your question and not in a partial screen shot. These details should include the steps you have already taken and more clarity as to the issues you are facing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Choosing the right interpreter environment:
Ctrl+Shift+P --> Python: Select Interpreter

